# STM32F103 hangs on page update with USART enabled

Tags: embedded, stm32, cortex-m

I am currently working on a STM32F103, and I want to program the flash. However, it appear that programming the flash with an USART device receiving bytes in the same time make it hangs:

```
FLASH_BASE->CR |= FLASH_CR_PER;
while (FLASH_BASE->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY);

FLASH_BASE->AR = pageAddr;
FLASH_BASE->CR |= FLASH_CR_STRT; // Hangs forever when receiving
                                 // data on USART2 in the same time
while (FLASH_BASE->SR & FLASH_SR_BSY);
FLASH_BASE->CR &= ~FLASH_CR_PER;
```

Disabling the RE flag on USART2 before and re-enabling it after avoids the problem, but it prevent me from receiving data during the operation, which would be possible since the receive interrupt is in the RAM.

Actually, looks like it is not related to the interrupt itself, because it still hangs without the receive interrupt.

Any idea?

Comment: Is the interrupt vector table still in flash?

Comment: Actually, my problem was an error in the handling of the UART, in the libmaple
See: https://github.com/leaflabs/libmaple/issues/109
And: https://github.com/leaflabs/libmaple/issues/107
The RXNE flag was not correctly checked during the interruption
Moreover, I've moved the uart interrupts to the RAM section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STM32 Flash memory interface locks its *entire* data bus during erase and write operations, such that any read operation is stalled during the access  A Page erase can take up to 40ms on an STM32F1xx (it is a massive 800ms on an STM32F2xx!).  Because the code is also running from the flash memory, instruction fetches and therefore code execution stall during that time, delaying interrupt handling and causing a USART overrun error.

One somewhat complex way around this is to use DMA for the USART receiver, but that is not always possible or straightforward and may not solve other problems caused by the processor stall in real-time systems.

This little surprise nugget is hidden in the [Flash Programming Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/CD00283419.pdf), separate from the [Reference Manual](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf):

> During a write operation to the Flash memory, any attempt to read the Flash memory will
>   stall the bus. The read operation will proceed correctly once the write operation has
>   completed. This means that code or data fetches cannot be made while a write/erase
>   operation is ongoing.

While the actual timing information is in the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00161566.pdf):
[image: STM32F103 Flash Timing]

They seem to have spread the information around separate documents to elicit maximum surprise at this gotcha!

Comment: Actually, my problem is not that is "stall" for 40ms, but it just hangs forever

Comment: I *never* execute any code after my page START if UART data is received during my page erase

Comment: Moreover, even if I put the code that erase the page in the RAM AND the interrupt of USART in the RAM it still hangs

Comment: I was not suggesting that the "hang" you observe was for 40ms; rather that the handling of the subsequent error such a delay may cause may cause a "hang".  For example if a USART overrun occurred because of the bus stall, and the overrun flag were not cleared, your ISR would continuously re-enter and never return to the main thread.  What does your debugger say?

Comment: Even if the USART ISR code and the programming code are in RAM, other any thread or ISR in flash that may preempt or block these (higher priority) can stall and thus cause a similar delay.  Note that code execution from RAM is typically slower than from on-chip flash on Cortex-M because it forces data and instruction fetches onto the same bus so they must happen sequentially.

Comment: OK
It was indeed caused by a problem of USART handling by the libmaple, that was fixed recently
See https://github.com/leaflabs/libmaple/issues/109